# Newlines in Spreadsheet ML when read by Excel

Tags: xslt, spreadsheetml

I'm trying to write a XSLT to produce a Spreadsheet ML to be further read by Excel and run into a problem with newlines. I need to add a newline to cell data. I made a sample in Excel to check the Excel idea of newline and got the following:

```
<Data>abc&#10;def</Data>
```

Here the `&#10;` reference is a newline and Excel understands it just fine when it reads the file back. I try to produce the same with XSLT, but, naturally, I get a true 0x0A (LF) character instead, so my XML looks so:

```
<Data>abc
def</Data
```

This doesn't seem to agree with Excel way to represent newlines and when I open the file in Excel I get no newline.

I tried to research the problem, but got nothing except the [following short discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/0b16067a-8754-4162-a6c1-5ef73c3e8e4c) which doesn't really give a solution and suggests it may be a bug in Excel. (**UPDATE:** As far as I understand this is what the specs call "accidents of encoding" and an XML parser must not rely on them, while Excel does.)

Is there a way to work around this somehow and get a literal `&#10;` in output instead of the LF character? Or maybe solve this in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Excel has its own way of distinguishing between a `LF` character and a character reference `&#10;` to that character.

I think with XSLT 1.0 if you want to force a character reference then doing `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&#10;]]></xsl:text>` is the brute force way.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me: it produces the same real LF character wrapped into `![CDATA[]]`.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use, how do you use it? Are you sure you have the right syntax `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&#10;]]></xsl:text>`? The `![CDATA[]]` in your comment suggests you forgot the `<` before the `!`.

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad; I was piping it through `xmllint` and it ate up the entity. Yes, it works! :) Many thanks.